# awk append lines if certain field matches

Tags: awk

I'm an absolute beginner to awk and would like some help with this.

I have this data:

```
FOO|BAR|1234|A|B|C|D|
FOO|BAR|1234|E|F|G|H|
FOO|BAR|5678|I|J|K|L|
FOO|BAR|5678|M|N|O|P|
FOO|BAR|5678|Q|R|S|T|
```

Desired output:

```
FOO|BAR|1234|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|
FOO|BAR|5678|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|
```

Basically I have to append some fields to the lines where column 3 matches.

Appreciate any responses, thanks a lot!

Comment: Suppose an extra line `PQR|XYZ|5678|D|C|B|A|` is added at the end; should the `D|C|B|A|` be added to the last line of your sample output, or should it be a new line of output?  Put another way, are you sure it is just column 3 as the question currently says, or do you mean 'the first three columns' which seems more plausible.

Comment: Processing: split on pipe symbols; keep a record of the old value in column 3; if the old and current values are the same, add columns 4-7 to the current row; if the old and current values are different, print the old row (if there is one) and then set the old value to column 3 and save the current record so it can be added to later.

Comment: `FOO|BAR|5678|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|D|C|B|A` - this would be the result if the extra line will be added. The data I'm working with has these fields with the same values.

Comment: Didn't take into account `PQR|XYZ|` since the data I have always has the same data `FOO|BAR|` for these columns.

Comment: Is the data sorted by column three? Or even if not sorted, will the same column-three values always be grouped together? (I.e., in your example, once we see `5678` can we be sure we'll never again see `1234`?)

Comment: Yes jas, the data is sorted by column three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
 awk -F"|" '$3 in a{
     a[$3]=a[$3]"|"$4"|"$5"|"$6"|"$7;
     next
}
{ a[$3]=$0
}
END {
     for ( i in a) {
         print a[i]
     }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -f chain.awk < data
FOO|BAR|1234|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|
FOO|BAR|5678|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|
$ cat chain.awk 
BEGIN   {FS = "|"}
$3==old {for(i = 4; i <= NF; i++) saved = saved (i>4?"|":"") $i}
$3!=old {if(old) print saved ; saved = $0 ; old = $3}
END     {print saved}
$
```

- `BEGIN` we set the field separator
- `$3==old` we append the fields `$4 ... $NF` to the saved data, joining the fields with `|` except for the first one (note that there is a last, null field)
- `$3!=old` we print the saved data (except for the first record, when `old` is false) and we restart the mechanism
- `END` we still have saved data in our belly, we have to print it